# Toggle activated window in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and can not figure out the best way how to toggle the `active` state between two elements. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Icon1 from '../../../../img/icon1.png';
import Icon2 from '../../../../img/icon2.png';


const Container = styled.div `
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
`;

const Option1 = styled.div `
    width:50%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: ${props => props.active ? 'var(--primary)' : 'var(--background)'};
    border-radius: 24px 0px 0px 24px;
    border: var(--border_primary);
`;

const Option2 = styled.div `
    width:50%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: ${props => props.active ? 'var(--primary)' : 'var(--background)'};
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0px 24px  24px 0px;
    border: var(--border_primary);
    color: white;
`;

const Image = styled.img `
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--subtle)
`

const Text = styled.p `
    color: ${props => props.active ? 'var(--on_primary)' : "black"};
`


class Contribution extends React.Component {

    toggleActive = () => {
        console.log('activated')
        this.props.active = !this.props.active;
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                <Option1 onClick={this.toggleActive}>
                    <Image src={Icon1}/>
                    <Text>Chcem finančne prispieť konkrétnemu útulku</Text>
                </Option1>
                <Option2 active onClick={this.toggleActive}>
                    <Image src={Icon2}/>
                    <Text>Chcem finančne prispieť celej nadácii</Text>
                </Option2>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Contribution;
```

Obviously the way I have it now throws an error when I click either on `Option1` or `Option2` element. I am sure there is a good and painless way how to make this work. One of them must be pre-set `active` on loadout.

What I need to achieve is, when user clicks on either of the elements, it's background and text color will change and It will pass the property of either element based on this `active` state to state - but did not get to this point yet.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Why don't you use the State?

Comment: not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Where are your variables declared? Like `var(--primary)` or `var(--background)`.
Without them, It will change nothing.

Comment: they are rendering fine, they are in the App.css at root. I can see in the console when I pass the event from click there is no `value` nor anything particulary straight forward that would determine which one I have clicked. I need each of them to send different value to props when clicked.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I have updated my answer. That code works fine for me, if I replace `var()` with some colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Code (Added 2 states for individual options):-

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
`;

const Option1 = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: ${({ active }) =>
    active ? "var(--primary)" : "var(--background)"};
  border-radius: 24px 0px 0px 24px;
  border: var(--border_primary);
`;

const Option2 = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: ${({ active }) =>
    active ? "var(--primary)" : "var(--background)"};
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px 24px 24px 0px;
  border: var(--border_primary);
  color: white;
`;

const Image = styled.img`
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--subtle);
`;

const Text = styled.p`
  color: ${({ active }) => (active ? "var(--on_primary)" : "black")};
`;

class Contribution extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeOption1: false,
      activeOption2: false,
    };
  }
  toggleActiveOption1 = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeOption1: true,
      activeOption2: false,
    });
    console.log("activated", this.state);
  };
  toggleActiveOption2 = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeOption2: true,
      activeOption1: false,
    });
    console.log("activated", this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Option1
          active={this.state.activeOption1}
          onClick={this.toggleActiveOption1}
        >
          <Text>Chcem finančne prispieť konkrétnemu útulku</Text>
        </Option1>
        <Option2
          active={this.state.activeOption2}
          onClick={this.toggleActiveOption2}
        >
          <Text>Chcem finančne prispieť celej nadácii</Text>
        </Option2>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Contribution;
```

Comment: but this solution only sets the `active` prop true or false, but I need to be able to change styling of the `Option1` or `Option2` element based on which one was clicked. this `true/false` state will be switching between those 2 options no matter which one I click. I can keep clicking on left one and it will be switching styling of left/ right element round and round..

Comment: Then pass the `active={this.state.active}` prop to your component.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I have added it to the component like this, but nothing happens, it keeps triggering the false/true state no matter which one I click

`<Option1 onClick={this.toggleActive} active={this.state.active}>`

Comment: If I click one of them twice, it should keep its `active` status since it is being selected

Comment: So, you mean, the user can select only one option at a time?

Comment: exactly, he can only select one or the other, not both together

Comment: okay. Thanks for the clarification. I have found out that the variables like `var(--primary)` and `var(--background)` are not there. That's why it was doing nothing.